# Yodlee - Retrieving bank data in the US but "tranListFromDate" and "tranListToDate" properties are null

Tags: date, onlinebanking, bank, yodlee

I am using Yodlee to retrieve bank account transaction details for a real-world US bank.

I am retrieving a lot of transaction data, but I was surprised to see the "transListFromDate" and "tranListToDate" properties of the BankData class have a NULL value for both of them.

I am wondering if these are always NULL for all "bank" containers/sites supported by Yodlee, or if this is just an issue with this particular bank.

If these date fields ARE populated with some banks, can anyone supply me with details (possibly sample sample values) about these related properties for these particular dates?

1. displayTimeZone (string)
2. localFormat (string)
3. timezone (string)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eden, these data elements are usually not set. 
"transListFromDate" indicates the "Transaction From date" and "tranListToDate" indicates the "Transaction to date" used during the last refresh attempt respectively and hence is of no much significance. It does not represent the complete transaction duration range that the user has.

Comment: So would you suggest to not store these fields with our detailed bank transaction data?  My guess is no since you cannot rely on it for the actual range.

Comment: Yes, we should not store these fields as its not of much value add to store this fields with bank transaction or account data.